# C Pointers to Structs Question - What does the " * " means when it is before a variable of a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Bellow there is a simple code which asks the last name, and 2 grades for 5 persons separately. It also 
finds the mean of all the grades and who has the higher grade.The question is about " * " symbol.

My professor is calling a function which is called readstudent(Tstudent *pstu); 
What does * before pstu means, and why is it necessary?

Also when we go through readstudent(Tstudent *pstu) why there is "&" for grade 1 and 2 and there is no "&" for the name?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct student
{
    char name[20];
    float grade1;
    float grade2;
} TStudent;



void readstudent( TStudent *pstu );
void printstudent( TStudent stu );
int main( void )
{
int N = 5;
        TStudent a[N]; int i, imax; float max, mo, sum;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        readstudent( &a[i] );
        printf("\n Oi karteles twn foitntwv einai:\n");
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        printstudent( a[i]);
        sum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        sum = sum + (a[i].grade1+a[i].grade2)/2;
        mo = (float)sum / N;
        printf("\nO mesos oros bathmologias tns taksns einai %2.2f\n", mo);
        imax = 0;
        max = (a[0].grade1+a[0].grade2)/2;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        if ((a[i].grade1+a[i].grade2)/2 > max)
        {   
            max = (a[i].grade1+a[i].grade2)/2;
            imax = i;
        }
printf("\nO/H foitntns/tria me ton ypsnlotero meso oro (%4.2f) einai o/h %s.\n", max, a[imax].name);
return 0;
}

void readstudent( TStudent *pstu)
{
printf("Eisagwgh foitntn/trias: epwnymo <keno> bathmos1 <keno> bathmos2 <keno>: \n");
    scanf("%s", pstu->name);
    scanf("%f", &pstu->grade1);
    scanf("%f", &pstu->grade2);
}
void printstudent( TStudent stu)
{
    printf("Epwnymo: %s\n", stu.name);
    printf("Bathmos-1: %4.2f\n", stu.grade1);
    printf("Bathmos-2: %4.2f\n", stu.grade2);
}
```

Thanks for your time, appreciate your help!

Comment: Basically it means pointer, also it's not clear, why did you tagged your question with `c#` tag

Comment: I'm a little worried why you're calling a function "sub-program".  It's a function.  Allow me to point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list which may help you

Comment: This is not even C++, but legacy C.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  sorry my bad I fixed it ! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @UKMonkey Thanks for your help

Comment: @SamVarshavchik excuse me, my bad I fixed it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Chris very welcome :)

Comment: I'm worried that you know pointers are involved but you still don't know what * means here.

Comment: Has your professor not gone over basic pointer syntax at all?

Comment: @JohnBode he has, but I didn't manage to understand them from the first try.

Comment: @user253751 hmm I can understand that my example "void readstudent( TStudent *pstu );" has a pointer as an input which is type TStudent. But i can't understand where it is pointing at first and after.

Comment: @Chris Then I'm worried that you know functions are involved but you still don't know how functions work.

Comment: @user253751 indeed I am slightly confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, quick crash course on pointers in C.

First of all, *why* do we use pointers in C?  Basically, we *have* to use pointers for the following reasons:

1. To allow functions to modify their parameters
2. To track dynamically allocated memory

Pointers come in handy in other ways, because they offer a form of *indirection*.  They allow us to manipulate other objects without having to know the other objects' names.

---

Indirection is a powerful tool in programming, one that you've already seen if you've dealt with arrays.  Instead of creating 100 unique integer variables, we can create an array of integers, and use subscripting to refer to a specific object.  That is, instead of writing

```
int var0 = 0;
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
...
int var99 = 99;
```

we can write

```
int var[100];

for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  var[i] = i;
```

Array subscript notation allows us to refer to an object *indirectly*, rather than by a unique name.  It provides a shortcut for managing large numbers of objects by referring to them with a single expression.  Pointers serve much the same purpose.  Suppose we have several integer variables named `x`, `y`, and `z`.  We can create a pointer `p` to refer to each one in turn:

```
int x = 10; 
int y = 20;
int z = 30;

int *p;
```

Let's start by playing with `x`.  We set `p` to point to `x` using the unary `&` address-of operator:

```
p = &x; // int * = int *
```

The type of the variable `p` is `int *`.  The type of the *expression* `&x` is `int *`, and the value of the expression is the address of `x`.  We can then change the value of `x` *through* `p` using the unary `*` indirection operator:

```
*p = 15; // int = int
```

Since the type of the variable `p` is `int *`, the type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, and that expression designates the same *object* that the expression `x` does.  So in the line above, we're changing the value stored in `x` *indirectly* through `p`.  We can do the same thing with `y` and `z`:

```
p = &y;
*p = 25;
p = &z;
*p = 35;
```

---

Okay, cool, but why not just assign to `x`, `y`, and `z` directly?  Why go through the *pain* of assigning their addresses to `p` and assigning values through `*p`?

Normally we wouldn't do it that way, but there's a case where it can't be avoided.  Suppose we want to write a function that modifies the value of one or more of its parameters, like so:

```
void foo( int x )
{
  x = 2 * x;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
int main( void )
{
  int val = 2;
  printf( "before foo: %d\n", val );
  foo( val );
  printf( "after foo: %d\n", val );
  return 0;
}
```

What we *want* to see is

```
before foo: 2
after foo: 4
```

but what we *get* is

```
before foo: 2
after foo: 2
```

It doesn't work because C uses a parameter-passing convention called "pass-by-value" - in short, the formal parameter `x` in the function definition designates a separate object in memory than the actual parameter `val`.  Writing a new value to `x` doesn't affect `val`.  In order for `foo` to modify the *actual* parameter `val`, we must pass a *pointer* to `val`:

```
void foo( int *x )     //  x == &val
{                      // *x ==  val
  *x = *x * 2;
}

int main( void )
{
  int val = 2;
  printf( "before foo: %d\n", val );
  foo( &val );
  printf( "after foo: %d\n", val );
  return 0;
}
```

*Now* we get the output we expect - `val` is modified by `foo`.  The *expression* `*x` refers to the same object that `val` does.  And now we can write something like

```
 foo( &y );   // x == &y, *x == y
 foo( &z );   // x == &z, *x == z
```

This is our first use case - allowing a function to modify its parameters.

---

There are times during a program's execution where you need to allocate some extra memory.  Since this allocation occurs at runtime, there's no way to specify a *name* for this extra memory the same way you do for a regular variable.  IOW, there's no way to write

```
int x = new_memory();
```

because variable names don't exist at runtime (they're not preserved in the generated machine code).  Again, we must refer to this dynamically allocated memory *indirectly* through a pointer:

```
int *p = malloc( sizeof *p ); sizeof *p == sizeof (int)
```

This allocates enough space for a single `int` object, and assigns the address of that new space to `p`.  You can allocate blocks of arbitrary size:

```
int *arr = malloc( sizeof *arr * 100 );
```

allocates enough space for 100 `int` objects, and sets `arr` to point to the first of them.

This is our second use case - tracking dynamically allocated memory.

---

A quick note on pointer syntax.  There are two operators associated with pointer operations.  The unary `&` operator is used to obtain the address of an object, while the unary `*` dereferences a pointer.  Assume we have an `int` object named `x` and a pointer to an `int` named `p`:

```
 p = &x; // assign the address of x to p
*p =  10; // assign a new value to whatever p points to
```

In a declaration, the unary `*` indicates that the thing being declared has pointer type:

```
int *p; // p has type "pointer to int"
```

When you *initialize* a pointer in a declaration like

```
int *p = &x;
```

`p` is *not* being dereferenced.  That is the same as writing

```
int *p;
p = &x;
```

The `*` operator binds to the thing being declared, *not* to the type specifier.  You can write that same declaration as

```
int* p;
int       *         p;
int*p;
```

and it will always be parsed as `int (*p);`.

For any type `T`, the following are true:

```
 T *p;          // p has type "pointer to T"
 T *p[N];       // p has type "array of pointers to T"
 T (*p)[N];     // p has type "pointer to array of T"
 T *p();        // p has type "function returning pointer to T"
 T (*p)();      // p has type "pointer to function returning T"
```

Complex pointer declarations can get hard to read, since the unary `*` is a prefix operator and has lower precedence than the `[]` and `()` operators.  For example:

```
T *(*(*foo)())[N];
```

`foo` is a pointer to a function returning a pointer to an N-element array of pointers to `T`.

---

With your code, we're dealing with the first case - we want the `readstudent` function to modify the contents of an existing instance of `struct student`.  And `readstudent` does that by calling `scanf` to read values into each separate member:

```
scanf("%s", pstu->name); 
scanf("%f", &pstu->grade1);
scanf("%f", &pstu->grade2);
```

Remember that `scanf` expects its arguments to be pointers - again, we're trying to modify the contents of an object, so we have to pass a pointer to that object as the parameter.

`&pstu->grade1` evaluates to the address of the `grade1` member of the object that `pstu` *points to*.  `&pstu->grade2` evaluates to the address of the `grade2` member of the object that `pstu` points to.

So what the heck is going on with `pstu->name`?

Arrays are special in C.  Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize an array in a character declaration like

```
char foo[] = "test";
```

an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

We won't go into the weeds on this, but this was a deliberate design decision by Ritchie when he was first creating the C language, and it does serve a purpose.  It also means that arrays lose their "array-ness" under most circumstances, and what you wind up dealing with is actually a pointer to the first element, not the whole array itself.  In the case of the `scanf` call, we're passing the *equivalent* of `&pstu->name[0]`.

Comment: appreciate your help sir! Really thank you a lot, for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`*` means different things in different *contexts*. Remember that C (and C++) is a *context sensitive* language.

When you declare a variable, like; `int* foo;` the `*` means that `foo` is a "pointer to `int`".

When you write a statement like `printf("%d", *foo);` the `*` means *dereference* the pointer stored in `foo` and give me the `int` value it points to.

When used in a function declaration like `void f(int* bar)` it means that the function accepts a pointer to an integer as its argument.

It can also mean multiplication, like in `int something = baz * 42;`

Or it can just be a plain character in a character literal, with no special meaning. Like `const char[] foo = "bar*baz*";`.

Comment: Add the answer regarding scanf for float member. So the answer will be complete for all question asked above.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer a slightly different question first; but related.
"what does `void printstudent( TStudent stu );` do?"

The answer is it takes a copy of the of the argument, and then does something with it.
By taking a copy of the data; it's unable to edit what was originally passed in.

Now we get to "what does `void readstudent( TStudent *pstu );`" do:

which is that it takes a copy of the pointer to some data.  This will allow it to edit the data that is being pointed to.

As Jesper states; there are many other uses of *; but these are the basics that you need to know to understand THIS usage